# How do I convert my program into a looping program

Tags: java

Here is what my program looks like so far.

```
package fahrenheit;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Steve
*/
public class Fahrenheit {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO code application logic here
    String name; // city name
    double temperatureInF; // original temperature
    double temperature; // converted temperature

    // declare an instance of Scanner to read the datastream from the keyboard.
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get name of city
    System.out.println ("Hello, please enter name of city: ");
    name = kb.nextLine();

    // get temperature in Celsius
    System.out.println("Enter current temperature in " + name + " (celsius): ");
    temperature = kb.nextDouble();

    // convert to degrees Fahrenheit
    temperatureInF = ((temperature *9/5)+32);

    // output statement
    System.out.println(" The current temperature in " + name + " is " + temperature + " \u00b0C" + " which is " + temperatureInF + " \u00b0F");
}

}
```

Now what I need it do is to produce a table of 40 temperature conversions from Celsius to Fahrenheit. So if the user input 0 as the starting degrees celsius then the output would create a table

Celsius Fahrenheit

0          32.0

1            33.8

2             35.6

3             37.4

4             39.2

5             41.0

etc up to 40. How would I get started and tweak my program to something like this?

Edit: Got everything except this very last thing

Here is my output statement

```
 // output statement
     System.out.println("\nCelsius" + "\t Fahrenheit" + temperatures[i][0] + " " + " " + temperatures[i][1]);
}
}
```

However this gives me

Celsius  Fahrenheit 0.0  32.0

Celsius  Fahrenheit 1.0  33.8

What do I change so my output statement looks like the one below?

Celsius Fahrenheit

0  32.0

1 33.8

Comment: [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: do you want 40 different inputs from the user or do u just want to increment the first value 40 times and create the table?

Comment: Increment the first value 40 times and create the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know how to use loops but you are confused about how to add it in your program.

You can first create a 2D array,

```
double[][] temperatures = new double[41][2];
```

Then you can place a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
{

        temperatures[i][0] = temperature+i; // increments temperature and adds value to array, temperature in celsius
        temperatures[i][1] = (((temperature+i) *9/5)+32); // temperature in Fahrenheit

}
```

Note: You asked for a loop that automatically increments temperature 40 times and stores Celsius, Fahrenheit values.

```
package fahrenheit;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Steve
*/
public class Fahrenheit {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO code application logic here
    String name; // city name
    double temperature; // temperature in Celsius
    double[][] temperatures = new double[41][2]; // stores temperature values

    // declare an instance of Scanner to read the datastream from the keyboard.
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    // get name of city
    System.out.println ("Hello, please enter name of city: ");
    name = kb.nextLine();

    // get temperature in Celsius
    System.out.println("Enter current temperature in " + name + " (celsius): ");
    temperature = kb.nextDouble();

    for(int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
    {

        temperatures[i][0] = temperature+i; // increments temperature and adds value to array, temperature in celsius
        temperatures[i][1] = (((temperature+i) *9/5)+32); // temperature in Fahrenheit

    }

    System.out.println("\nCelsius" + "\t Fahrenheit");
    for(int i = 0; i < temperatures.length; i++)
    {

        // output statement
        System.out.println(temperatures[i][0] + " " + " " + temperatures[i][1]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I am a little confused about how to use loops as well. Could you show me where to add your code into my program to receive the result I am looking for? Do I remove my current output statement since I am now looking for 40 results instead of just one conversion

Comment: Wow thanks a lot its almost perfect.   1. It goes to 39 instead of 40 and 2. How would I make my output statement into the table I am looking for instead of the general statement

Comment: I actually needed a tiny bit more help but hitting 'enter' enters the comment instead of creating a new line. I edited my previous comment

Comment: You can change array size from 40 to 41. I just edited my code. And to print as a table, you can just tweak around the print statement, check the output loop  I just edited in my post.

Comment: Very last thing can you take a look at my edit on my original main question. At the bottom, with my output statement

Comment: Print "\nCelsius" + "\t Fahrenheit" before your loop starts so it gets printed only once, then you can print all 40 values in loop. Check edited output code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=userInput; i<=40+userInput; i++)
    convertAndOutput(i)
```

Something like this should work (pseudoCode)

If the user inputs 5 it will range from 5-45, which should be what your question asked for.

Obviously you will need to add a string/float(or int, if there should only natural numbers being entered) conversion for the user input, etc etc... (But since your are using the Scanner that should be a nobrainer)

**EDIT:**

As to your request in comments, here is the full code:

CtoF.java:

```
package com.company;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class CtoFLoop {
    public CtoFLoop(int userInput, int until) {
        for (int i = userInput; i <= until + userInput; i++)
            convertCtoFAndOutput(i);
    }

    public static String CtoF(int celsius) {
//      (°C * 1.8000) + 32 = °F
        return new DecimalFormat("#0.00").format(((double) celsius * 1.8000d) + 32d);
    }

    private void convertCtoFAndOutput(int celsius) {
        System.out.println(celsius + "°C" + " = " + CtoF(celsius) + "°F");
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CtoFLoop(new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).nextInt(), 40);
    }
}
```

Sample Output, when entering "0":

```
0°C = 32.00°F
1°C = 33.80°F
2°C = 35.60°F
3°C = 37.40°F
4°C = 39.20°F
5°C = 41.00°F
6°C = 42.80°F
7°C = 44.60°F
8°C = 46.40°F
9°C = 48.20°F
10°C = 50.00°F
11°C = 51.80°F
12°C = 53.60°F
13°C = 55.40°F
14°C = 57.20°F
15°C = 59.00°F
16°C = 60.80°F
17°C = 62.60°F
18°C = 64.40°F
19°C = 66.20°F
20°C = 68.00°F
21°C = 69.80°F
22°C = 71.60°F
23°C = 73.40°F
24°C = 75.20°F
25°C = 77.00°F
26°C = 78.80°F
27°C = 80.60°F
28°C = 82.40°F
29°C = 84.20°F
30°C = 86.00°F
31°C = 87.80°F
32°C = 89.60°F
33°C = 91.40°F
34°C = 93.20°F
35°C = 95.00°F
36°C = 96.80°F
37°C = 98.60°F
38°C = 100.40°F
39°C = 102.20°F
40°C = 104.00°F
```

Comment: Yes that is what my question asked for, can you please break it down for me in non psuedoCode if possible?